# Regex for telephone number with or without spaces

Tags: regex

How do I create a regex that matches telephones with or without spaces in the number?

I have found:

```
^\+?\d+$
```

From another post but how do I modify that to allow 0 or more spaces in the number?

Comment: google around, you can find existing regexes that you could throw in your code that'll be more comprehensive than what you have here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to think is the exact format you want for phone numbers containing spaces. Eg:

```
+535 233 4444
```

Is that one OK? It means divided like: `3 3 4`. You can adapt the following regex to your needs:

```
^\+?\d{3}\s?\d{3}\s?\{d}{4}$
```

Just change the quantifiers (`{3}`, `{4}`, etc) to change the group lengths.

Answer (score 0):

This is one example:
    /^(?:\s*\d{3})?\s*\d{3}\s*\d{4}\s*$/

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to match telephone numbers (and a lot of valid telephone formats). Here's a simple regex to match "5555555555", "555 555 5555", "(555) 555-5555", "555-555-5555", or "555.555.5555"

^(?\d{3})?( |-|.)?\d{3}( |-|.)?\d{4}$